# Is there a way to send my IP packets to say node "r" inside network A from a node "y" in network B via SSH?

Tags: networking, ssh, openssh

I have two networks A and B consisting of linux nodes and I want to communicate between the two via SSH:

- Both networks are separated by the internet.
- Network A is behind a firewall, and allows only SSH connections to the nodes in it.
- Network B consists of two nodes.
- I want to be able to send a packet to any of the nodes in Network A.
- But note that the nodes in network A can't be accessed directly over the internet using a specific IP as only SSH is allowed.
- I do not have access to any of the firewalls for NAT.

How can I achieve this communication?

Is there a way to send my IP packets to say node "r" inside network A from a node "y" in network B via SSH?

Answer (score 0):

You need NAT for this. You have to configure NAT in your firewall. This might look something like this:

- Source: WAN IP of A
- Source Port: any
- Destination: WAN IP of B
- Destination Port: 22
- Redirect to: LAN IP of B

You need to do this on both sides.

I hope that this is what you meant.

Comment: the problem is the I dont have access to firewall of network A, only the nodes in it. And network B has no firewall in it just nodes; which i also have access to.

Answer (score 0):

The proper way to do this would be to let the firewall do NAT (Network Address Translation) that maps the nodes behind it to different IP addresses. However, that may not be possible if you have only one IP address on the Internet side, but multiple nodes behind the firewall. In that case, the firewall could offer Port Address Translation. That means that packages sent to the firewall on port 22 are forwarded to port 22 on node "r", packages sent to port 23 are forwarded to port 22 on node "s", and so on.

Comment: the problem is the I dont have access to firewall of network A, only the nodes in it. And network B has no firewall in it just nodes; which i also have access to. so i can't do any port address translation.

Comment: You could ssh to one node, then ssh on to another node from there. Perhaps you can build a small menu on the first node that offers a choice of nodes to ssh to, or to stay at the first.

Answer (score 0):

You can set up an IPSec or OpenVPN tunnel on both firewalls. That way, you can ignore the internet and treat both networks as being on the same LAN.
There are many tutorials on both technologies on how to set them up. Google is your friend or open a new thread in this forum.

Once the VPN tunnel has been set up, you can still use your firewall to secure the link.

Comment: the problem is the I dont have access to firewall of network A, only the nodes in it. And network B has no firewall in it just nodes; which i also have access to.

Comment: If you don't have access to the firewall or router on those networks, you should talk to your system admin. Or you could set up your own firewall (e.g. pfsense) but it would help if you could use a public IP on it. If you have a dynamic IP address, then there are other ways around that with free or paid services online.